# Array is not array anymore when passed into Vuex action function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

EDIT: Added extra code in the **filterEvents** snippet for more context.

I'm not quite understanding what's going on with my code. I'm trying to pass an array into an action function inside of my Vuex store. If I return a Promise inside of that action function, then the parameter being passed isn't of type Array and is instead an Object, which results in the reject() error that I have for the Promise.

Here's some code for context:

```
filterEvents({ commit }, events) {
    console.log(Array.isArray(events)); //this ends up false
    console.log(events);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!Array.isArray(events)) {
            reject("Invalid argument: is not of type Array.");
        }

        let filtered = events.filter((event) => {
            let now = new Date();
            let event_stop = new Date(event.stop_time);

            if (event_stop >= now || event_stop == null) {
                return event;
            }
        });

        resolve(filtered);
    });
}
```

Here's where I call **filterEvents**; inside of **getEvents**;

```
getEvents({ state, commit, dispatch }, searchParams) {
    .....
    
    eventful.getEvents(searchParams).then(async (res) => {
        .....

        console.log(Array.isArray(res.data.events.event)); //this ends up true
        console.log(res.data.events.event);

        /* where I call it */
        await dispatch("filterEvents", res.data.events.event).then((res) => {
            .....
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
        .....
    });
}
```

Here's the output from the Chrome developer console. First two outputs are from **getEvents** and last two are from **filterEvents**

[image: Chrome Developer Console]

Would really like an explanation as to why this is the case. I'm going to bet it's something small, but it's 3 a.m. at the moment and my brain can't wrap around why it's not of type Array when passed into **filterEvents**.

Comment: I have a feeling that it might be argument order, because the object you log looks suspiciously like the context-object you destructure in `getEvents`.

Comment: @Thomas, well the weird thing is that it was working when I didn't make filterEvents return a Promise. I initially had filterEvents filter the array that was passed in using events.filter(event => my conditions.....), then I would do a state mutation using commit('setEvents', filtered). That was working, but now it doesn't work also because I get the same thing as what's shown on my log.

Comment: @Thomas, I think I finally understood what you initially meant. I figured out what my issue was, and yes it was pretty small. I didn't know that Vuex actions had to have two arguments if it's expecting a payload to be passed into the function. I just ended up doing filterEvents(context, events) even though I'm not using the context variable in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understood what my issue was after taking another look at the object that was being logged on the console. I did not know that Vuex actions HAD to have two arguments if you want to pass in a payload into that function. For example, I initially did this

```
filterEvents(events) {
    .....
}
```

but what I really needed to do was

```
filterEvents(context, events) {
    .....
}
```

The context argument is the object that allows you to do things such as commit and dispatch. I usually destructure the context object (i.e. { commit, dispatch} ), so I for some reason never thought twice about it. You don't have to destructure the context object to use commit and dispatch; if you don't it would just be like

```
context.commit('function', payload);
```

Answer (score 0):

I always try to check the length prop of the array which helps me out in such cases.

```
...
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!Array.isArray(events) && !events.length) {
            reject("Invalid argument: is not of type Array.");
        }

        .....
    });
...
```

Comment: Although this adds an extra layer towards error handling, it doesn't actually change my situation. I appreciate the answer though.